# How to disable underline for <i> tag inside <u> tag?

Tags: html, css, underline

Here' the example:

```css
u i {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;  
}
```

```html
<u>
  Underlined text
  <i>Text without underline</i>
</u>
```

Actual result:

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

What should I do to disable underline for `<i>` inside `<u>`?

Comment: Have your code like this `<u>
  Underlined text</u>
  <i>Text without underline</i>`

Comment: First step: stop using `<u>` and `<i>`. I lost track what their current status exactly is but there were good reasons to stop using them. Use semantic markup instead. This will also force you think about what you *actually* want to accomplish here in terms of markup.

Comment: First of all, why you want to use <i> inside <u> tag. Each html element has own styles. You can use <div> instead of using <u>.

Comment: Just upvoted to express that I do not think "this is a bad question" ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why spend energy trying?

What I mean is: you **marked** your content with thee `<u>` tag; and now you want to have a special rule that underlined but *italic* text should only be *italic*, but not underlined?!

I think you better step back and look into your requirements; as the simple solution is: "end the `</u>` section when switching to *italic*".

And for the record: as TheYaXxE shows in his answer, it is technically possible. But I am with Konrad here - the fact that something *can* be done doesn't mean that it *should* be done this way.

Comment: You are answering like it is a bad question. It is not. You can style the italic so it is not bold in: `<b>test <i>test</i> test</b>`. Why can you not remove the underline from the italics in `<u>test <i>test</i> test</u>` ?

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen Just because you *can* doesn’t mean you should. This may not be a bad question per se but what OP wants to do *is* bad, and this answer explains why.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen "italic" is not an artefact like the underline is. A better analogue would be a background image, which you also can't get rid of easily in a nested child.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen Rest assured; if I would "answer it like it is a bad question" everybody would notice that. I am simply expressing my *concern* that the direct technical solution isn't necessarily the *correct* solution. But I hear you ...

Comment: Thanks a lot @GhostCat, "the fact that something can be done doesn't mean that it should be done this way" - this was just the right thing to hear.

Comment: @limonte You are very much welcome! Actually, really nice. It feels like one is only answering low quality questions from newbies all the time; and this here was just ... a nice experience on a different level ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't to suggest you should do it this way. It's a hack and non-semantic (as other users have mentioned). But to use your HTML structure and to answer your question as to how you can do it, here is the answer:

```css
u {
  display: inline-block;
}

u i {
  float: right;
  padding-left: 5px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<u>
  Underlined text
  <i>Text without underline</i>
</u>
```

Comment: Ooh, even better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to achieve what you want.

The most obvious way, would be to just have the u and i next to each other like this:

```css
i {
  color: red;  
}
```

```html
<u>Underlined text</u>
<i>Text without underline</i>
```

If you still want the two of them to be wrapped, just wrap them inside a span:

```css
span i {
  color: red;  
}
```

```html
<span>
  <u>Underlined text</u>
  <i>Text without underline</i>
</span>
```

Comment: <u>’s *only* purpose is to mark text as underlined. Removing this style makes the tag useless. Just omit it then.

Comment: I know. Made a dumb mistake while writing the code (facepalm) Thanks for letting me know. Corrected my answer

Answer (score 0):

> which is best to use a separate tag for underlined part

```css
i {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;  
}
span{
  text-decoration:underline;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Underlined text</span>
  <i>Text without underline</i>
</div>
```

Comment: This code makes *all* `<span>`s underlined (except when explicitly overridden). Not a good idea.

Comment: @ronald i just created an demo,you can use a class for that purpose

Comment: OK, but then I don’t see why OP should replace their use of `<u>` by `<span>` at all (though I generally think that `<u>` should be avoided anyway; and unrelatedly, that text except links shouldn’t be underlined).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Moreover , you cannot disable underline for `<i> inside <u>`.Its like you are trying to say red to black. Thanks!

```css
 i {      
  color: red;  
  }
```

```html
<u> Underlined text </u>
  <i>Text without underline</i>
```

Answer (score -1):

As the other answers already indicate, you shouldn't do this. Various reasons are given, which I'm not going to repeat here, and they're all good ones, so just don't. Just don't.

That said, there is a solution that doesn't require changing the markup, only the css.

```css
u i {
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color:white;
  color: red;  
}
```

```html
<u>
  Underlined text
  <i>Text without underline</i>
</u>
```

Comment: This solution fails in all browsers I tested (Chrome, Safari and Firefox on macOS, Edge on Widows).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yeah, I see you're right; MDN tells me that it isn't supported very widely. It works on Firefox on my machine though. At least, if the background colour is white;i's a shame there is no `currentBackgroundColor` in CSS, like there is for the foreground. Hm. And also, even if it would work everywhere, it still wouldn't have been the same as the OP's desired outcome, which has a non-underlined space in front of the <i>. So you were right to downvote my answer. You know what, I'll downvote it too. Edit: oh wait.